# Deprication error in flutter?C:\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\firebase_auth-0.20.0+1\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins

Tags: java, api, flutter, deprecated

i am facing this problem everytime i run any flutter app on my vscode.

Note: C:\flutter.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\firebase_core-0.7.0\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebase\core\FlutterFirebaseCorePlugin.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: C:\flutter.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\flutter_facebook_login-3.0.0\android\src\main\java\com\roughike\facebooklogin\facebooklogin\FacebookLoginPlugin.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: C:\flutter.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\firebase_auth-0.20.0+1\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebase\auth\FlutterFirebaseAuthPlugin.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.

Answer (score 0):

This [link](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/36014#issuecomment-524959958) helped me solve this issue:

In your app build.gradle, update the `minSdkVersion` to `23`